# Parse Json file in HDFS and write to output only if key is available

Tags: shell, hdfs, jq

I have a JSON file with "name" as key and "url" as another key. Not all records in the JSON have the "url" key. So when I am trying to write to text it gets written as null. So, I will have to do a check if url key is present and if present, then it has to be written to 2 output text files. name will goto name.txt and url will goto url.txt

```
{ [ {"name": "a", url: "url1"}, {"name": "b"}, {"name": "C"} ] }
```

Expected output:

```
name.txt
a
url.txt
url
```

What i tried so far:

```
name=`hdfs dfs -cat $path | jq -r '.name'`
url=`hdfs dfs -cat $path | jq -r '.name'`

echo ${name} >> name.txt
echo ${url} >> url.txt
```

The problem with above is if url is not found it writes a null to output file and equivalent name is written to name.txt file.

How to skip the records from writing to output file when url json tag is not found

Comment: Your input is invalid JSON. Also, the question is quite unclear, not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Please fix the line containing the second invocation of `hdfs`

Answer (score 1):

Evidently you need first to `select(.url)`.

Calling both hdfs and jq twice seems a bit extravagant. If efficiency is a concern at all, you might wish to save the result of hdfs to a file and call jq twice, or perhaps even better to contrive to call hdfs and jq just once in a pipeline that ends with a call to awk to write the two files.